# state not updating for globally scoped variable

Tags: javascript

I'm not understanding why count will not update. Its globally scoped and I've verified that the functions are firing when the add/subtract buttons are clicked. The other examples I've found are a bit too complicated for me at this stage since I'm new to programming.

```
//target the proper elements
let add = document.getElementById('add');
let subtract = document.getElementById('subtract');
let span = document.getElementById('result');

//starting data
let count = 0;

//add to count
function addCount() {
    count++;
}

//subtract from count
function subtractCount() {
    count--;
}

//display the count
span.innerHTML = count;

/************Event Listeners*************/
add.addEventListener('click', addCount);
subtract.addEventListener('click', subtractCount);
```

Comment: Setting `innerHTML` sets it once. You need to set it again when the data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Count is changing. Problem is you're not changing the display. This should work:

```
//add to count
function addCount() {
    count++;
    span.innerHTML = count;    
}

//subtract from count
function subtractCount() {
    count--;
    span.innerHTML = count;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let add = document.getElementById('add');
let subtract = document.getElementById('subtract');
let span = document.getElementById('result');

//starting data
let count = 0;

//add to count
function addCount() { 
  count++;
  span.innerHTML = count; // you need to update span for every count update
}

//subtract from count
function subtractCount() {
  count--;
  span.innerHTML = count; // you need to update span for every count update
}

//display the count
span.innerHTML = count; // this code runs only one time

/************Event Listeners*************/
add.addEventListener('click', addCount);
subtract.addEventListener('click', subtractCount);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id='add'>add</button>
  <button id='subtract'>subtract</button>
  <span id='result'></span>
</body>
</html>
```